# How to pass data from URL to JQuery toggler initShow function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

A webpage has several collapsed divs and I want to append data to URL when linking to that page, so the URL will tell this script which particular div to expand when the page is loaded.

This function expands a div with class *.currview* on page load

```
$("h3.expand").toggler({initShow: "div.currview"});
```

How to replace `"div.currview"` in `({initShow: "div.currview"})` with data appended to URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this maybe..

given that I have http://something.com?collapse=currview
first is get the URL params via

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}​
```

then

```
var collapse = GetURLParameter('collapse');
$("h3.expand").toggler({initShow: "div."+collapse});
```